# Best screenshot utility for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen capturing and annotating tool under OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/30587/screen-capturing-and-annotating-tool-under-os-x)

Several versions of this question have been asked, but I'm looking for something specific:  what screenshot app for the Mac is closest to the Windows [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) utility that you would recommend?

Comment: As Doug Harris mentioned in his answer, this question has been asked before here: http://superuser.com/questions/30587/screen-capturing-and-annotating-tool-under-os-x

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what FastStone is, but i'm using Skitch. It has:
- simple editing tools for screenshot;
- upload to skitch.com or your ftp server;
- simple saving to different formats;

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to [another question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/30587/screen-capturing-and-annotating-tool-under-os-x/30665). See the suggestions there for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/). It's got video recording functionality as well. If you pay for the pro version, you can save in non-flash formats or even upload to YouTube. Jing also lets you use your webcam, should you be using a machine that has one.

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight, fast, efficient, does 100% of what a simple screenshot program does. I use FastStone Capture on Windows extensively, and so far, I find that [InstantShot!](http://projects.digitalwaters.net/index.php?q=instantshot) replicates FastStone Capture the best, without adding all the bells-and-whistles that I hardly, if I ever, uses.

[image]

Give it a whirl, you'll like it. Oh, and it's free too!